# Sharepoint 2013 Powershell Script

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, powershell

I am looking for some direction as for some ps script (or something else - we do not have a vs environment setup) I may use to populate the title field of any document from a document library. When document are dragged in the name field is populated but not the title field - I want all names and titles to be the same.

Comment: You want to update the Title field which is empty when the Documents drag and drop on document library ? or You want to fetch the documents whose title is empty ?

Comment: This should be doable fairly easily by Workflow which can be set up using SharePoint Designer (no need for VS)

Comment: I couldn't get it to work through SP designer. Wouldn't update older existing items. Any suggestions?